# \hspace{50pt} no effect in the title of a tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-styles, boxes

Please consider my minimal example and tell me why the \hspace{50pt} command has no effect in the box title. Is there another way to place an empty input field in the title?

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% Design für Boxen
\newtcbox{\blank}[1][red]{
on line,
height=2em,
arc=7pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=1pt,
boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows,raster columns=3,,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white]
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=1, height=4cm,title=\blank{\hspace{50pt}}]
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=2, height=4cm, title=\blank{Erläuterung}]
    Text 1
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=1, height=4cm,title=\blank{\hspace{50pt}}]
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=2, height=4cm, title=\blank{Erläuterung}]
    Text 2
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `\hspace{50pt}` you should use `\hspace*{50pt}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}% Design für Boxen
\newtcbox{\blank}[1][red]{
on line,
height=2em,
arc=7pt,colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
before upper={\rule[-3pt]{0pt}{10pt}},boxrule=1pt,
boxsep=0pt,left=6pt,right=6pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows,raster columns=3,colframe=red!50!black,colback=red!10!white]
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=1, height=4cm,
             title=\blank{\hspace*{50pt}}] % <---
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=2, height=4cm,
             title=\blank{Erläuterung}]
    Text 1
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black, colback=blue!10!white, raster multicolumn=1, height=4cm,
             title=\blank{\hspace*{50pt}}] % <---
    \tcbitem[colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!10!white,raster multicolumn=2, height=4cm, title=\blank{Erläuterung}]
    Text 2
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]